# Make Julia Installing: it shows hashing.o not found?

Tags: makefile, julia

I had installed Julia 0.4.5 with `sudo apt install julia`. Now I want to install the latest version of Julia v0.6.0. First I git clone the source code from the Github, then I install lots of the dependencies following the installing instruction.  And all is fine.

When I start to `make`, waiting a long time, and it show:

```
Making install in TESTS
Making install in EXAMPLES
Making install in BAND
Making install in COMPLEX
Making install in NONSYM
Making install in SIMPLE
Making install in SVD
Making install in SYM
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/yaoyu/julia/src/support/hashing.o', needed by '/home/yaoyu/julia/src/support/libsupport.a'. Stop.
Makefile:208: recipe for target 'support/libsupport.a' failed
make[1]: *** [support/libsupport.a] Error 2
Makefile:55: recipe for target 'julia_flisp.boot.inc.phony' failed
make: *** [julia_flisp.boot.inc.phony] Error 2
```

I have searched for answers in this web, while cann't find the way to fix it, I don't know what causes that ? Anyone konws how to correct it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you checkout version 0.6 using git? Otherwise you will be trying to build the development version. Also it would be useful to know what system etc. you are using.

Comment: @AlexanderMorley Thanks.I'm glad To hear from you. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and before installing I had git checkout v0.6.0-rc3 ('git tag' shows the latest is v0.6.0-rc3). Now maybe  I should try To install JuliaPro. So far I cannot fix that.

Comment: You should be able to `git checkout release-0.6`, which is more recent.